# Size of C array returns unexpected value

Tags: c, clang

Absolutely flummoxed over this:

if the array length is set to 5 in the declaration, `int a[5]` then I get the expected result from `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])`. However, with `int a[10];` as below, `sizeof(a)` returns `50` and `sizeof(a) / sizefo(a[0])` returns `12`. Cannot see through this. Is my compiler gone bad?  Using clang on OS X 10.9.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {

    int a[10];
    size_t n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    printf("sizeof(a): %lo\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("sizeof(a[0]): %lo\n", sizeof(a[0]));
    printf("%lo\n", n);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What made you use `%lo` in your format string? The answer to *that* is the real problem.

Comment: Did that while looking up the `stdio.h` description in the dinkum C99 library and completely overlooking the default base for the conversion specifier. I was trying to address a compiler warning about the conversion specifier I was using previously for `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` (%d). This will stay with me for a while!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're printing the numbers in **octal** notation!

050 (octal) == 40 (decimal), and 012 == 10 as expected.

Change all of your `%lo` to `%ld` to display the values in decimal.

Comment: I cannot believe I just did that and spent 30 minutes trying to figure it out with 5 different size arrays! I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes as SO stipulates, thanks.

Comment: `%ld` is for `long int`, whereas the `sizeof` expressions have type `size_t`.  `%zu` prints a `size_t`. If you have a pre-1999 compiler that doesn't support `%zu` then you can use `%lu` and cast the value to `(unsigned long)`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Wouldn't that be a pre-1999 libc, not compiler? `</pedantic>`

Comment: by 'compiler' I mean 'implementation'

Answer (score 0):

50 in octal = 40 in decimal

These lines print the numbers in octal.

```
printf("sizeof(a): %lo\n", sizeof(a));
printf("sizeof(a[0]): %lo\n", sizeof(a[0]));
printf("%lo\n", n);
```

Change them to below to print in decimal.

```
printf("sizeof(a): %ld\n", sizeof(a));
printf("sizeof(a[0]): %ld\n", sizeof(a[0]));
printf("%ld\n", n);
```